# Why does Validation attribute accepting constructor parameter does not accept variables

Tags: c#, validation

I was trying to write the following code -

```
[Range(DateTime.UtcNow.Add(-7).Ticks, DateTime.UtcNow.Add(7).Ticks)]
public DateTime TimeStamp;
```

The compiler reported the error - An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

The error is self descriptive, it is okay. My question is - what is the rationale to not allow expressions / variables / method calls as argument for any Attribute in C#?

Comment: Maybe a way to clarify your question: This is by no means specific to *Validation* attributes, it is a restriction of any attributes.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, thank you for the clarification. I observed this with ValidationAttribute, thus the question. But I shall edit the question to ask for Attribute in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because attributes are stored as *metadata*, their values should be known at compile time so they can be stored after the code is compiled and don't change at runtime.